# Rust Actix Web with HTTPS - stream error: request parse error: invalid Header provided

Tags: nginx, rust, https, actix-web

I am working on a project with a simple web server using Rust actix_web. I have set up an HTTP server, running on port 4000:

```
HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .wrap(Logger::default())
            .wrap(Cors::default().allow_any_header().supports_credentials())
            .service(test_index)
    })
    .workers(4)
    .bind(("0.0.0.0", 4000))?
    .run()
    .await
```

I am really just trying to nail down the basics here. I was able to hit the server using HTTP just fine.

I have this running in a docker-compose project with port 4000 mapped to port 4000 in the container. Now, I have added an nginx container, running on the same network as the actix container. It has configured a directive in the nginx config to handle SSL / TLS handshaking, and pass requests through to the actix container. The import pieces of the nginx config are here:

```
server {
        listen 4000 ssl http2 default_server;
        listen [::]:4000 ssl http2 default_server;

        include /myserver/serverName.conf;
        server_tokens off;
        client_body_buffer_size 2048K;
        client_max_body_size 2M;

        location /myserver/ {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://myserver:4000/;
        }

        ssl_certificate /myserver/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /myserver/privkey.pem;
        ssl_dhparam /myserver/dhparam.pem;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-CCM:DHE-RSA-AES256-CCM8:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-CCM:DHE-RSA-AES128-CCM8:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256;
        ssl_ecdh_curve X25519:prime256v1:secp384r1;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_session_timeout 1d;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;

        add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    }
```

When I send a request (using either my browser or curl) over HTTPS, I am getting the following error in actix web:

```
2023-10-29T01:32:01.137392Z TRACE actix_http::h1::dispatcher: parse error invalid Header provided
2023-10-29T01:32:01.137888Z TRACE actix_http::h1::dispatcher: read half closed; start shutdown
2023-10-29T01:32:01.137907Z ERROR actix_http::h1::dispatcher: stream error: request parse error: invalid Header provided
```

Any idea what I am missing here? With HTTPS, do I need to have any additional configuration in actix if I already have nginx to do the heavy lifting?

I have tried messing with the configuration in nginx to remove the headers I pass through to the actix server, but that still didn't change anything.

I have also tried adding Cors configuration and allowing all headers.

I plan to try to write some middleware for actix to print out the headers I receive on a request. I realized there is a duplicate of this issue, but the guidance is not very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended by Actix to use built-in feature by setting up the feature flag

you can see the examples here : https://github.com/actix/examples/tree/master/https-tls/rustls

don't forget to set flag feature in **cargo.toml**

```
actix-web = { version = "4.2.1", features = ["rustls-0_21"]}
```

Comment: I am glad you solved it, here are the feature flag docs if you need them, https://docs.rs/crate/actix-web/latest/features